# WCF service returns Error:System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationException:

Tags: wcf, xml-validation

My application is accessing a WCF service hosted at the server.
When i try to call a Method with [WebInvoke] attribute the response returned is always "error".
All other methods with [WebGet] attribute are working fine.

The interface as in the reference.cs is

```
 [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0")]
 [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName="SyncService.IService")]
 public interface IService
 {


 [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]  
 [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="", ReplyAction="")]
 [System.ServiceModel.FaultContractAttribute(typeof(DataSynchronization.SyncService.WebExceptionDetail), Action="Update", Name="WebExceptionDetail", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/xxx.WebServices")]
 string Update(string mode, string data);

  }
```

whenever i try to call the Update method of the service using the code

```
string response = objClient.Update("manual", string data);
```

the response obtained is "Error".and the log displays

> Error -
>   "System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationException:
>   The element 'providers' cannot contain
>   text. List of possible elements
>   expected: 'provider'". on calling
>   Update

The service is hosted in a remote server which i cannot debug either.

Comment: Since the error refers to the XML that you sent, you should probably edit your question to include the XML that you sent.

Comment: You can debug on remote also. Put PDBs if it is not Production environment. Otherwise simulate the similar environment in same machine.